# Reach certain Wiki page through random links

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just read about Wiki game on Wikipedia and wanted to implement it as a fun project for myself using python.

Task:To reach Mathematics Wikipedia page using wikipedia hyperlinks randomly.

Using Beautiful Soup documentation,I was able to create following crude code which is quite slow for my purpose.

```
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content) 
a = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')]
del a[0:6]
while(soup.title.text != 'Mathematics - Wikipedia'):
    a = [link.get('href') for link in soup.find_all('a')]
    del a[0:6]

    if (a == []):
        add = "/wiki/Special:Random"
    else: 
        add = random.choice(a)
        if(add == None):
            add = random.choice(a)

    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/"+add
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    print(soup.title.text)
```

**First,I would like to reduce the useless links that this program goes through such as About Wiki,user login,etc.** 
I knew I can simply use if-else statements but wanted to know if there is another simpler or faster implementation for it in beautiful soup or something else.

**Secondly,Any suggestions to improve code would be welcome including additional reading resources.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has an API available. You can make calls to e.g. `"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles={title}&pllimit=500"` and get back a list of titles the Wikipedia page `title` links to, without all the internal links (but with non-existing pages and things like categories).

Incidentally, there is even a python package available that makes using it a lot easier, [`Wikipedia-API`](https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/). With this your code would become:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import wikipediaapi
import random
from itertools import count

WIKI = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')

def random_page():
    r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    page = WIKI.page(soup.title.text[:-12])
    assert page.exists()
    return page

BLACKLISTED = ["Wikipedia:", "Category:", "Template:", "Template talk:", "User:",
               "User talk:", "Module:", "Help:", "File:", "Portal:"]
def blacklisted(title):
    return any(title.startswith(x) for x in BLACKLISTED)

def random_walk(target_title):
    page = random_page()
    for i in count():
        print(i, page)
        if page.title == target_title:
            return i
        links = list(page.links.values())
        # print(f"{len(links)} links")
        if not links:
            return None
        page = random.choice(links)
        while blacklisted(page.title) or not page.exists():
            page = random.choice(links)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(random_walk('Mathematics'))
```

This still needs to blacklist some pages (see `BLACKLISTED` constant, the content of which I found by trial-and-error) and I'm not quite happy about the trial and error way of getting a random page, but filtering for existing pages needs to fetch them all, which is quite slow.

In any case, this *should* be a bit faster than actually getting the whole page and parsing it yourself.

I also put the code into function and guarded the calling under a `if __name__ == "__main__":` to allow reusing of the code. In doing this I took the liberty of adding a counter and returning it in case the target page is found (12000 pages and counting...).

---

Another question is if this is the best/most fun way to play this game. The way I know it, the goal is to reach a target page as fast as possible. In that case you will want to do a breadth-first search of all links instead (depth-first would fail because there are loops, meaning you could get lost forever). Although I have to admit, it is fun watching the bot and seeing where it wanders...

A good compromise might be checking if any of the links on the current page is to Mathematics, and only randomly jumping to the next page if not.

---

Some generic comments about your code:

- You don't need parenthesis around your conditions, and they are discouraged unless needed to make the condition span multiple lines.
- Empty lists are falsey, so you can replace `if (a == []):` with `if not a:`.
- Your code only tries twice to get a random page, which will work most of the time but will fail eventually. Instead use a `while` loop that continues indefinitely.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `if not a:`, since `a` as an empty list will be`False`?

Comment: @Linny Indeed, fixed!

Comment: Great answer!And to answer your question about the most fun way to play this game,I think,this is also a pretty fun just to see totally weird pages show up in your quest for Mathematics